# Accessing second parent method which is overridden in multiple inheritance

Tags: python-3.x

"i am unable to access the method of second parent class using super method but when i am using product in the super it is showing the result of methods inside phone class"

```
class Phone:

    def __init__(self, price, brand, camera):
        print ("Inside phone constructor")
        self.__price = price
        self.brand = brand
        self.camera = camera

    def buy(self):
        print ("Buying a phone")

    def return_phone(self):
        print ("Returning a phone")

class Product:

    def buy(self):
        print ("Product buy method")


class SmartPhone(Product, Phone):

    def call(self):
        super(Phone,self).buy()



s=SmartPhone(20000, "Apple", 12)
s.call()
```

"i am expecting the output from the Phone class instead i am getting error"

```
Inside phone constructor

Runtime Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file.py", line 26, in <module>
s.call()
File "file.py", line 22, in call
super(Phone,self).buy()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'buy'
```

Comment: When i am using super(Product,self).buy() , it is showing the output as :                              Inside phone constructor and  Buying a phone in the next line

Answer (score 0):

multiple inheritance:

```
class SmartPhone(Product, Phone):
    def call(self):
        Phone.buy(self)
        Product.buy(self)
```

output:

```
Inside phone constructor
Buying a phone
Product buy method
```

**Note:
if I understood well what you wanted. you are trying to use the function for the wrong purposes**

Here is an example of a class that inherits from three superclasses:

```
class D(C, B, A):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
```

Since you have called `__init__` on the super() object, this is essentially the same as calling all three super class `__init__` methods:

```
class D(C, B, A):
    def __init__(self):
       C.__init__()
       B.__init__()
       A.__init__()
```